# Why is the comma added?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, commas, participial-phrases, absolute-constructions, parenthetical-commas

Why is the comma added in the following?

> [The] Hyena crept slowly round, making the most of his spotted brown camouflaged fur against the brownish stems of grass.

Comment: Why would the comma **ɴᴏᴛ** be added in the foregoing and current examples alike❟ given your current model of understanding and previous research on this matter?

Comment: *previous research?* This is a new user, who probably *hasn't* read all the "rules" (and perhaps doesn't realise that this type of question is better asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that two clauses constitute this sentence, a main clause and a supplementive clause, and there is no grammatical indicator to show the start of a new unit (conjunction ("that, and, …"), relative pronoun, relative adverb); in fact, in certain cases of use of such an indicator, a comma is still used, either according to a grammatical principle (restrictive and non restrictive clauses) or not (syndetic coordination (and, or, …); moreover, the clause is long.

-- [The] Hyena crept slowly round
-- making the most of his spotted brown camouflaged fur against the brownish stems of grass

> (**CoGEL III.6**) One dominant use of the comma is to separate closely associated clauses within a sentence.

It is not true, for instance that coordinated clauses have to be separated by a comma, and when they are short a comma is often not found.

In this sentence, the comma appears to be essential as, even if the sense  indicates that "making … grass" is not a participle clause in function of postmodifcation of  "round", nor of verb complementation, nor of adverbial, it seems important to show clearly the start of another unit at the level of the sentence, in particular as the participle clause is long.

> (**CoGEL 15.62**) **Supplementive clauses in final position**
> In spite of their resemblance to nonrestrictive relative clauses, supplementive
> clauses need not be separated from their matrix clause intonationallv when
> they occur in final position. The following are therefore alternative renderings
> of the same sentence, differing only in that [1] has two focuses of information,
> whereas [2] has only one:
>
> - The manager apPRÔACHED us, SMÌLing.  [1]
> - The manager approached us SMÌLing.   [2]
>
> One result of the alternative shown in [2] is the possible neutralization of the formal difference between nonfinite clauses functioning as supplementive
> clauses and those functioning as complementation of the verb. Thus [3] is
> ambiguous:
>
> - I saw Pam going home. [3]
>
> On one interpretation (that of the supplementive clause), *I* is the implied
> subject of *going home*, whereas on the other (that of verb complementation),
> *Pam* is the overt subject.

Note that the comma in "[1]" corresponds to two tone units, and that only the use of two tone units makes sense in the sentence "[The] Hyena …".

No pause between "round" and "making" is typical of postmodification, and even if the syntax and sense do not correspond to postmodification the use of no comma leaves in the mind an impression of postmodification, and a pause seems natural for supplementive clauses (therefore a comma).

Note that if the position of the supplementive clause is initial, a comma is usual.

- Making the most of his spotted brown camouflaged fur against the brownish stems of grass, [the] Hyena crept slowly round.

*Compare*

In the following page of [Google examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22approached%20us%20smiling%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) notice that if the comma may or may not be used when the participle clause is at its shortest ("smiling"), it is almost always used when its length is more than one word.